# MYSQL: how to retrieve all table rows + only the last row where column equals

Tags: php, mysql

OK, a bit of a complicated query, for me anyway.

I'm trying to build a MYSQL query to retrieve all the rows from a DB, but I only want the last row where the column 'topic' equals 'This Week'.

So, what I mean is this:

I have a DB table with all my blog articles. Every week, I write a summary of the aviation news from the past week. I now want to show all the blog posts on the index page, but I also only want to show the last 'This Week' post.

This is the query I use now to retrieve all the rows:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE published = '1' ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 10
```

So I need a query that returns all the rows from my table 'articles' + only the last row where 'topic' = 'This Week'.

Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: More effiecient to just do 2 queries.. where each selects only what is needed.. Avoid select * when possible.  1st qry might look like
select title, pubdate, author from table where published=`1`
2nd might look like (using * here since we only need 1 record)  
`select * from table order by ID desc limit 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use Unions ( something like this

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE published = '1' ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 10
UNION
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE WHERE topic="This Week" order by ID desc LIMIT 1
```

you may use UNION or UNION ALL whichever suits your need

you may wanna check the actual query and format it as per your needs

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is indeed a good idea! But since I am using pagination, I need to limit my query, like this: `LIMIT $position, $item_per_page`. How would I go about limiting this entire union query? I can't get it to work.